Installing pluggy from .tar.gz file with version 1.4.0, but gets 0.0.0 version
I'm currently trying to create a virtual environment using the *.tar.gz files from Pypi, and when I install pluggy with the following command, I get the wrong version installed.
The command :
$ pip install --no-build-isolation pluggy-1.4.0.tar.gz

However, I get this message in my terminal :
Processing c:\users\user\pluggy-1.4.0.tar.gz
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
Building wheels for collected packages: pluggy
  Building wheel for pluggy (pyproject.toml): started
  Building wheel for pluggy (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
  Created wheel for pluggy: filename=pluggy-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl size=13687 
  Stored in directory: c:\users\user\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\33\fb\ef\8197200bbef89b55d3d5e18139488ab23ce89adb34c5547413
Successfully built pluggy
Installing collected packages: pluggy
  Attempting uninstall: pluggy
    Found existing installation: pluggy 0.0.0
    Uninstalling pluggy-0.0.0:
      Successfully uninstalled pluggy-0.0.0
Successfully installed pluggy-0.0.0

I already looked up stackoverflow and the github page, but couldn't find a fix.

I managed to install the correct version by using the compiled file from Pypi, and the command :
pip install --force-reinstall pluggy-1.4.0-py3-none-any.whl

